# Is it true that trees shouldn't present inside home?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, sanskrit, plants

Consider the following statement of Dhaumya from Mahabharatha

> Under the roots of a tree scorpions and snakes undoubtedly find
> shelter. Hence, one should never plant a tree within one's abode.
>
> [[Section 127, Anusasanika Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b092.htm#fn_290)

Since the above reason seems ambiguous to me, I want to know the actual Sanskrit verse and its literal translation. Please provide me with the source statement and its translation.

Do any other scriptures also support this argument from Mahabharatha?

Comment: Let's wait for scriptural answers, but as for scientific reasons more than 90% of the trees or plants should not be plant inside home as their odours, roots, etc can attract poisonous insects, animals, reptiles etc at home plus at night trees emits carbon dioxide which is very harmful and poisonous for health and the roots of the large trees can also destroy the foundation of house.

Comment: Actually planting mango banana etc is recommended

Comment: But still the roots can mess the foundation of the house so its better to plant it a bit away actually like in a garden or something which is highly recommended in architecture. As big trees have deep, strong and huge roots. Making a vedi around the roots also helps a bit in binding the roots in a particular region. Plus, it should be plant in such a way that it should not cover the entrance as its consider negative on vastu sashtra i guess. Prd..

Comment: In maharashtra it is common to plant curry leaves and lemon in house, which can be found in almost every house